# ios facebook sdk access token gets cleared every time I run my app from Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

After I login with my facebook account everything works fine, except the token gets cleared automatically every time i start the app, so it asks my to login again, i use the following code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to check active session:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
    NSLog(@"Found a cached session");
    // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"publish_actions,publish_stream"]
                                       allowLoginUI:NO
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"session exp. = %@",session.accessTokenData.expirationDate);
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error delegate:_delegate];

         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
         }
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[Utils languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Logout"] forKey:@"fbState"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error delegate:nil];

     }];

    // If there's no cached session, we will show a login button
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[Utils languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Login with Facebook"] forKey:@"fbState"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    NSLog(@"no cached session -> show a login button");
    //  UIButton *loginButton = [self.customLoginViewController loginButton];
    //  [loginButton setTitle:@"Log in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

so the Found a cached session message is printed, but when i check the session i found it cleared, what i noticed is the method `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` not called!!!

Any Suggestions, please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, i was using wrong permissions which did not allow me to store the session, so i edited the permissions as below:

```
@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"publish_actions"]
```

So after i removed `publish_stream` everything worked perfectly.